# How to read invalid JSON format amazon firehose

Tags: json, ruby, regex, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I've got this most horrible scenario in where i want to read the files that kinesis firehose creates on our S3.

Kinesis firehose creates files that don't have every json object on a new line, but simply a json object concatenated file.

`{"param1":"value1","param2":numericvalue2,"param3":"nested {bracket}"}{"param1":"value1","param2":numericvalue2,"param3":"nested {bracket}"}{"param1":"value1","param2":numericvalue2,"param3":"nested {bracket}"}`

Now is this a scenario not supported by normal JSON.parse and i have tried working with following regex: .scan(/({((\".*?\":.*?)*?)})/)

But the scan only works in scenario's without nested brackets it seems.

Does anybody know an working/better/more elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: I am curious why does this happen to you. When my Kinesis Firehose pulls records from Kinesis Datastream, I end up with a list of legit JSON objects.
Why does your Firehose behave in this way?

Comment: I think a key item is that we read from the firehose s3 files that get pumped into redshift.

Comment: @mowienay honestly i expected an newline seperated file, but checked and double checked and it's not stored that way on s3.

Comment: why don't you check the format of the data that was pushed to your Firehose in the first place. Possibly, something in the Firehose inbound data is causing this problem.

Comment: Pretty sure we send a stringyfied json object. Which might also explain the backslashes in the s3 files. Mmm i would need to build a test for that.

Comment: Ok, I guess you I got what is the problem. May be you stringify the whole json objects and then you push it to the firehosebas a single event.

Comment: What you should do is write your client to loop on your objects from and push it one by one to the firehose. Set your firehose buffer to accomodate the time and size needed to send all your data (possibly 128 MB / couple of mins). That way your forehose will buffer all your messages and store them in the bucket as a list of json objects. Then you can easily parse this list easily.

Comment: I have been checking the documentation etc.. but it seems that the behaviour i'm seeing is pretty normal, even found a link where they state, you should add newline characters yourself to ensure parsing is easy: 
https://medium.com/@pahud/kinesis-firehose-put-record-with-cli-e835a6e6ffe2

Also have checked our code. and the backslashing is normal behaviour as we are expected to send the json blob in the data: of the hash required by firehose. @mowienay let me know what you think, happy to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: I will add an answer to be able to write code freely @spons

Comment: having the same issue as you @spons when using `cloudwatch-logs > kinesis-firehose > s3`

Any success?

Comment: @lifeofguenter yes and no. I build finally a hell of a parser for the use case. As we run on a high load live application and didn’t have time to build a setup clean from scratch yet.

Comment: @lifeofguenter i would propose trying to add line delimiters yourself, be sure though that your data cannot contain it. Which was one of my biggest issues due too user text input and while they copy paste, they pasted linebreaks along

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/record-format-conversion.html
Fireshose stores it in a format which is compatible with Apache Hive JSON SerDe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one in the initial anwser is for unquoted jsons which happens some times. this one:

`({((\\?\".*?\\?\")*?)})`

Works for quoted jsons and unquoted jsons

Besides this improved it a bit, to keep it simpler.. as you can have integer and normal values.. anything within string literals will be ignored due too the double capturing group.

https://regex101.com/r/kPSc0i/1

Answer (score 1):

Modify the input to be one large JSON array, then parse that:

```
input = File.read("input.json")
json = "[#{input.rstrip.gsub(/\}\s*\{/, '},{')}]"
data = JSON.parse(json)
```

You might want to combine the first two to save some memory:

```
json = "[#{File.read('input.json').rstrip.gsub(/\}\s*\{/, '},{')}]"
data = JSON.parse(json)
```

This assumes that `}` followed by some whitespace followed by `{` never occurs inside a key or value in your JSON encoded data.

Comment: It’s sadly not a newline delimited json. And it’s not parseable as it’s simply a string of concatenated json object. Aws likes to follow the standards huh? Not Haha

Comment: @spons I have updated my answer and added a variant that should hopefully work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

As you concluded in your most recent comment, the put_records_batch in firehose requires you to manually put delimiters in your records to be easily parsed by the consumers. You can add a new line or some special character that is solely used for parsing, % for example, which should never be used in your payload.

Other option would be sending record by record. This would be only viable if your use case does not require high throughput. For that you may loop on every record and load as a stringified data blob. If done in Python, we would have a dictionary "records" having all our json objects.

```
import json
def send_to_firehose(records):
  firehose_client = boto3.client('firehose')
  for record in records:
    data = json.dumps(record)
    firehose_client.put_record(DeliveryStreamName=<your stream>,
                               Record={
                                       'Data': data
                                      }
                              )
```

Firehose by default buffers the data before sending it to your bucket and it should end up with something like this. This will be easy to parse and load in memory in your preferred data structure.

```
[
    {
        "metadata": {
            "schema_id": "4096"
        },
        "payload": {
            "zaza": 12,
            "price": 20,
            "message": "Testing sendnig the data in message attribute",
            "source": "coming routing to firehose"
        }
    },
    {
        "metadata": {
            "schema_id": "4096"
        },
        "payload": {
            "zaza": 12,
            "price": 20,
            "message": "Testing sendnig the data in message attribute",
            "source": "coming routing to firehose"
        }
    }
]
```